# Windows 7 - Elevated Command Prompt Context Menu

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, user-permissions

I realize the Vista trick of typing  `cmd` then `SHIFT+CLICK+END` from the Search menu gets you a privileged terminal session.

Has anyone found the necessary tweaks to turn this capability into RIGHT+CLICK folder convenience?

Comment: What do you mean by Shift+Click+End? I usually do Orb, cmd, Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 5):

Try [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.06.elevation.aspx). Was originally written for Vista, but I'm sure it works fine on 7.

Comment: Great link... I'll try this.  Up-voted for now.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something obvious about your question here, but if you type cmd from the start/run/search menu, you can already right-click on it and choose "Run as Administrator".

Comment: I think he was talking about the ability to right-click on a folder in Explorer and run it with higher privs (so you can do things UAC prevents you from doing otherwise).

Comment: Exactly right, I was looking for Explorer context choice (or RIGHT+CLICK).

Answer (score 0):

since you're talking about a folder, you can't 'run' it as such.. but you can 'Take ownership'.

Assuming that's what you mean, there are basically two versions of a reg file posted around the internet.

**What not to do:**
Like a number of others, I merged one that adds 'Take ownership' to the context menu. Idiot. The side effect of that approach is to lose 'Run as administrator', including rt click on command prompt in the Start Menu. It took a while to untangle that, as the 'undo' reg file usually offered on such pages is incomplete.

**What to do:**
The one you want is the one that requires you to SHIFT and rt click - the version with 'Extended' in the .reg file keys.

Thus you SHIFT + right click on a file or folder, and get a 'Take Ownership' context entry.
This is somewhat context dependent, thus where you already obviously have ownership- say your desktop- the entry doesn't appear.

You can download it here: 
http://www.technobeta.com/posts/add-take-ownership-option-to-the-windows-vista-context-menu/

The long-winded detail for 'take ownership' is here: yyyy://xxx.vistax64.com/tutorials/67717-take-ownership-file.html
(“TOCM_add.reg”).
It adds a helpful note about this and .exe files.

The reg file to add the context menu entries is here:
yyyy://xxx.petri.co.il/add-take-ownership-context-menu-vista.htm

"Take Ownership" needs to be used while logged on to an administrator account. When you use Take Ownership on a folder, it will also take ownership of the files and subfolders.

**Using a .cmd file instead:**
yyyy://xxx.vistax64.com/tutorials/112795-context-menu-take-ownership-2.html
(scroll down to 'Sidney1st') offers another approach, using a .cmd file rather than a context entry).

(had to modify the URL as the site only allows posting 1, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

Add / remove right  click option to take ownership of files in Windows 7 - just download this archive, use any of the links below:

```
http://rapidshare.com/files/323827396/takeownership.zip.html
http://www.zshare.net/download/701700850749b580/
http://www.megaupload.com/?d=KJXHXTJ9
http://depositfiles.com/files/km5rss81j
```